# Is a number with infinite digits within the set of natural numbers?

Tags: definition

I have 237474 ..... that number should be found within the set of natural numbers
no?
because if we say that the set of natural numbers has infinite elements, therefore that number should be found in the set.
if that is not the case then what set is it in?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The set of natural numbers has infinitely *many* elements, but the elements themselves are finite

Comment: If the digits extend infinitely to the _left_, then you get [$p$-adic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number). But these are not natural numbers.

Comment: Does that means that the number is not an integer ?

Comment: @IsraelRamirez It's not that 'the number is not an integer' ... but that the 'infinite string of digits is not a number'

Answer (score 4):

No, that does not follow. There are infinitely many natural numbers, but the decimal representation of each natural number is only a finitely long string of digits.

An infinite string of digits would be in the set of .... strings of digits.